# Почему не выводятся русские буквы?

Tags: python

Использую pdfkit для создания pdf. В файле все символы выводятся нормально кроме русских.
Пример:

> ÐÐ‘Ð’Ð•Ð“Ð´ÑˆÑ†ÑˆÑˆÐ²Ñ„Ñ‹Ð²Ñ‰Ñ„Ñ‹Ñ‰Ñ†Ð¹Ñ‰Ñ‹Ñ„Ñ‘ 123132 dksadwofdadasdao

Код:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pdfkit

options = {
'encoding': 'UTF-8'
}

result = '''
АБВЕГдшцшшвфывщфыщцйщыфё 123132
dksadwofdadasdaos'''

pdfkit.from_string(result, f'test.pdf', options=options)
```

Comment: UTF8->1251, с таким запросом можно мучать гугл по вашей проблеме

Comment: Шрифты нужно встроить.

Comment: @eri, а как в pdfkit для python мне их встроить? в документации не нашёл способа.

Comment: https://pdfkit.org/docs/text.html#fonts